How to handle a array of Json object in Cosmos db using C#
I am working on an API which just add a record in a document which has the below JSON body.
My problem is the Status always shows null in CosmosDB.
I am sure the I am not handling the class definition for "Status" correctly. Status is an array of objects. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?
Json body:
{
    "name": "John", 
    "Status": [
        {
            "Status": "Closed",
            "StatusUpdatedDateTime": "2023-10-01T00:00:00Z",
            "StatusUpdatedBy": "XXX"
        }
    ]
}

Class definitions - TopObject class :
public class TopObject
{
     public string name { get; set; }
     public List<Status> status { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string Status { get; set; }  
    public DateTimeOffset StatusUpdatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string StatusUpdatedBy { get; set; }
}


You can't have a class member with the same name as the class.  Use [JsonProperty("Status")] and give the property any name other than "Status" (lowercase "status" was fine, albeit not the usual casing for a property).  Alternatively, give the class a different name so you can call the property "Status".

I agree with @madreflection, You can't have a class member with the same name as the class. Use [JsonProperty("Status")] and give the property any name other than "Status" (lowercase "status" was fine, albeit not the usual casing for a property). You can use define the classes as below:
public class TopObject
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public List<Status> Status { get; set; }
}
public class Status
{
    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("StatusUpdatedDateTime")]
    public DateTimeOffset StatusUpdatedDateTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("StatusUpdatedBy")]
    public string StatusUpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

Then you will be able to read the data successfully as shown below:

Here is the complete code for your reference:
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class TopObject
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public List<Status> Status { get; set; }
}
public class Status
{
    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("StatusUpdatedDateTime")]
    public DateTimeOffset StatusUpdatedDateTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("StatusUpdatedBy")]
    public string StatusUpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    private static CosmosClient cosmosClient;
    private static Container container;
    private static string endpointUri = "<endpoint>";
    private static string primaryKey = "<primaryKey>";
    private static string databaseId = "<dbName>";
    private static string containerId = "<containerName>";

    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(endpointUri, primaryKey);
        container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);
        string documentId = "<id>";
        var topObject = await GetDocumentByIdAsync(documentId);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + topObject.Name);
        foreach (var status in topObject.Status)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Status: " + status.status);
            Console.WriteLine("Updated Date: " + status.StatusUpdatedDateTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Updated By: " + status.StatusUpdatedBy);
        }

    }
    public static async Task<TopObject> GetDocumentByIdAsync(string documentId)
    {
        try
        {
            ItemResponse<TopObject> response = await container.ReadItemAsync<TopObject>(documentId, new PartitionKey(documentId));
            return response.Resource;
        }
        catch (CosmosException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.StatusCode}, {ex.Message}");
            return null;
        }
    }
}


There is no need to post a custom full example- the question was solved in comments, as a simple error that can be corrected. Just close as typo/could not reproduce.
